# Adding to CookieJar results in cookie data being cleared

Tags: go

I'm attempting to design a way in which I can take a cookie from a http.Client, store the raw cookie data, and then at a later point convert the raw cookie into a *http.Cookie and then add this to a http.CookieJar. As of now, it seems the cookie is being created correctly:

```
fmt.Println(cookies)

[MyCookie=ab4d4e5a-38a3-4f23-aa9f-90cbe40419c1; Path=/; Domain=mydomain.com; Expires=Tue, 24 Mar 2020 00:35:26 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure]
```

However when I try to add this cookie to a jar, it seems to remove most of the data:

```
jar, _ := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})
jar.SetCookies(domain, cookies)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", jar.Cookies(domain))

[MyCookie=ab4d4e5a-38a3-4f23-aa9f-90cbe40419c1]
```

Is this an intended behaviour of the standard cookiejar or is there perhaps another approach I can take?

Comment: "Is this an intended behaviour of the standard cookiejar" Yes, 100%. And this behavior cannot be changed or customized. The cookiejar.Jar takes care of what cookies to return in which request (which is complicated). There are forks of net/http/cookiejar which allow access to all data, but the one from stdlib doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookiejar simulates a cookie client, which is used to manage the cookies distributed by the server. The cookies obtained through the `cookies()` interface are the data that the client needs to send to the server, which does not include the path, expiration time, etc., which the server needs to tell the client, while the client only needs to tell the name and corresponding value of the cookie

Comment: This! Couldn't have explained better!